# Run SSH without ANY Authentication

Tags: security, authentication, ssh

I know it flies in the face of the very notion of a "secure shell," but I would like a way to run SSH that requires absolutely no authentication whatsoever. I have a collection of machines that run on a totally air gaped network. It's used for a hardware prototyping project, and for reasons beyond my understanding some of these machines occasionally start asking for a password regardless of the fact that they have all been cloned with the same SSH keys that work some times.

I'd really like to side step all the security issues that can prevent SSH from connecting to a machine. I've seen in other posts people strongly recommending against what I am trying to do; but I've wasted enough time trying to fight SSH's security features. Is there a flag I can use? A change to a config file? Another version of SSH I can install?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can simply use telnet instead of SSH if you don't care about security. That's what we did back before SSH was the norm.

Comment: Air gaps are great for security, but they don't help attacks from within, so going with `rsh` or `telnet` is a bad idea.  A keyless ssh key stored in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` with its pubkey stored on the host's corresponding `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` should work 100% of the time.  I'd encourage you to use `ssh -vvv` and log that output so you can see why it fails.  Otherwise, I suppose you can hard-code passwords and use `$SSH_ASKPASS` to supply them, but you should really fix your config and use keys.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [sf] or [unix.se].

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want a 'remote shell', so try `rsh`.

Comment: Looks promising, thank you.